# URLEncoder not giving any value

Tags: android, url

this is my code :

```
 try {
            data = URLEncoder.encode("product_name", "utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[1], "utf-8");
            data +="&"+URLEncoder.encode("product_price", "utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[2], "utf-8");
            data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("product_flag", "utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("2", "utf-8");
            Log.d("Parth", "data"+data);
            new Hiturl().execute(data,url);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Parth", "Error:"+e.getMessage());
        }
```

there is no entry in the log about it. 
not even "data:"
if my data was empty then i should get at least data: as my log output

Comment: you might have written it in any conditions, or check if there is any exception

Comment: no i am not getting error of any form. i am trying to connect android via an phpserver with POST method thats y i am adding these values

Comment: It is possible that it is throwing some exception, and it is going to `catch` block. So the logs might not have executed. Make sure there is no exception. Check `params[1]` and `params[2]` for `null` values.

Comment: if you are trying to view logcat with "data:" then you will not get anything in your logcat just try "data" or "Parth".

Comment: it happens that sometimes i get value and sometimes i dont. why is that happening. ?